# 2G disconnects Frequently

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, data-connection, mobile-network, 2g

I have Intel XOLO (X900), I use a Airtel data connection(India). The network in my mobile 2G
disconnects whenever I go home(at home there is poor network coverage). After I come out of my house, still the 2G is not enabled,even after enabling the mobile data multiple times.
Every time I had to switch off the mobile and then start to get the 2G connection.

Any idea on what's wrong?

Comment: Are you the only one experiencing this? How about other people who are on the same network in your area? Are they also getting poor signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not your Device problem, It is Airtel's Problem. Airtel.in website was on off because of server down.
And the problem you are facing is very common, As i am also suffering from that and here [some more](http://www.grahakseva.com/topic/airtel-network). I would suggest you to disable your data connection whenever your network circle is changing. Like while you are travelling.

But the solution of this problem is nowhere and can be solved by airtel only.
FYI : I have a vodafone sim too and it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Most of us are experiencing the same issue,

Sometimes in home there is no packet data, only city areas we are having great connectivity,

This is because of Heavy network traffic, Load on serves which they are not able to transfer to another Base Station,

If you observe carefully at peak hours your network will be down as between 6 to 10...

It's not device fault it's most probably Service provider/Mobile company's fault and Indian govt.. due to poor devices/setup less satellites for telecommunication & more number of peoples in one network